# How to prove 'For a symmetric distribution with zero mean, the population MAD is the 75th percentile of the distribution'

Tags: mathematical-statistics, median, quantiles, mad

**For a symmetric distribution with zero mean, the population MAD is the 75th percentile of the distribution**

I came across this statement in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation#The_population_MAD) for MAD(Median Absolute Deviation)

but could not come up with anything on how to prove it?

Any easy-to-understand solution or hint should be good.

Comment: For a symmetric distribution with mean zero, the median is also zero.  The MAD is thus the _median_ of the absolute deviation from 0. Look at all the positive values of $X$. What is the number $\theta$ such that half the positive values are larger than $\theta$ and half the positive are smaller? Clearly the 75th percentile.  By symmetry, half the negative values of $X$ are smaller than the 25th percentile and half are larger.  Exercise: what's symmetry got to do with the matter? Why won't it work for $f_X(x)=\begin{cases}1,&-0.5<x<0,\\0.5e^{-x},&x>0,\end{cases}~~~~????$

Answer (score 1):

(Proof basically copied from comments)
For a symmetric distribution with mean zero, the median is also 0.  Then, it is enough to look at the positive part of the distribution. We want a number $\theta$ such that the probability a positive observation is larger than $\theta$ is 1/2, and the probability it is lower than $\theta$ is also one half. But that is clearly the third quartile $Q_3$. By symmetry we get the corresponding result for the negative part of the distribution as $Q_1$, the first quartile (whose absolute value is $Q_3$).  That should establish that the MAD, median absolute deviation from median is $Q_3$.

Comment: One needs to interpret this argument carefully: the MAD will be *a version* of Q3 but it might differ from a *conventional* Q3.  Consider the dataset $(-2,-1,0,0,0,0,1,2)$ for instance: although its Q3 is usually taken to be $0,$ the MAD is the median of $(2,1,0,0,0,0,1,2),$ which conventionally is $1/2.$ Thus, the two `R` implementations as `function(x) quantile(x,3/4)` and `function(x) median(abs(x-median(x)))` may return different values.